# Did CNN journalist say that Chechens are from Czech republic?

Tags: united-states, geography

While there is little doubt that some Twitter users are not the brightest bunch (see: [Are Americans ignorant about the geography of the world?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15913/are-americans-ignorant-about-the-geography-of-the-world) ), there are claims that same misinformation has been repeated by CNN journalist in a live broadcast. He allegedly said *"Islamist Czech Republic"*. Is that true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15913/are-americans-ignorant-about-the-geography-of-the-world

Comment: Actually, Russian soldiers call chechens like this: "chehi" which is a Russian toponym for people of Czech Republic. I don't know the actual reason why they do this, but I know this for sure. So a CNN journalist occasionally posted a misinformation that is a coincidence at the same time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a CNN journalist but an expert CNN were interviewing according to this [page](http://www.rferl.org/content/boston-chechen-czech-twitter-marathon-bombing-suspects/24963035.html) with a video capture of the CNN interview

The transcript of the CNN video includes

> "...and also, you know, the young brother, Dzhokhar, named after -- the similar name, anyhow, to the first president of the Czech Republic, the Islamic republic, that was formed there. So I don't know if there's anything about identity there, when you're given a name like that as a youth, um, what kind of, uh, what does that do to your mindset and your identity and what's expected of you. It'd be interesting to hear the profilers talk about that."

The comment on the Radio Free Europe page notes

> All three of the CNN anchors standing next to the man making the statement (who is identified by "tilna65," who posted the video, as a "former CIA agent" but whom we have not identified) appear to visibly shudder at the comment. But whether they actually failed to catch the mistake or simply regarded it as inessential or impolitic to set the record straight, none offers a correction: