# Were the responses in the "Can you name a country" video staged?

Tags: video

I recently watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRh1zXFKC_o) from Jimmy Kimmel where he would send his team on the street asking people if they could name / place a single country on a map. Obviously it didn't go well. **Is there any evidence that the responses in the segment are fake?** For example maybe they are using actors. Because the answers from some people are surprising to say the least.

If you know if other segment of the same kind, by that I mean Kimmel's crew asking questions to people on the street, are staged/fake too that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you ask 50 people to do this you can probably fill up the slot with the 6-8 notable "fails".  Note that they returned to one lady in particular several times.

Comment: They film a metric crapload of interviews, then broadcast the ones that were the funniest fails.  Don't expect entertainment to be a representative survey.

Comment: This is a weird question. Yes, everyone agrees it is staged. I don't think anyone denies that they cherry-pick. But that is different to claiming that they use actors. Do we need to show they don't use actors to satisfy you?

Comment: Related question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15913/are-americans-ignorant-about-the-geography-of-the-world

Comment: I'm asking to show me if it's fake, not the other way around. I don't understand how it is not clear from my text in bold ? If there is no evidence/testimony/whatever the answer is a simple no. I don't see why it's a weird question. Thanks for the link @AndrewGrimm.

Comment: There are no evidence that this is fake.

Comment: Looks pretty believable to me. In most clips, they look confused (the map is centred on the Pacific - most maps in USA are centred on the Atlantic?), panic a little under pressure, then make a silly mistake like saying Africa is a country (a very common mistake in the US apparently) or pointing roughly where somewhere is on Atlantic-centred maps. Correct answers appear to be edited out e.g. a hard jump suggests one lady correctly named some South American countries before failing to place (Central American) Honduras. Only the lady with black hair seemed to give up, failing to name anywhere.

Comment: Fake as in "those idiotic responses are staged," or fake as in "they edit out the responses that are not idiotic"?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Fake as in "those idiotic responses are staged", I know they edit out people who gives good answer there is no point in showing them. I obviously don't believe that this is a representative survey but rather a selection of bloopers and funny answers most of the time. I'm asking because I can understand not being able to place Tanzania on a map but your own country or next door neighbor like Canada or Mexico that seems pretty weird to me.

Comment: Based on your comments, I edited your question to focus on whether or not the responses are staged and voted to reopen it. Feel free to edit it back if it doesn't fit what you were looking to ask.

Comment: If the responses were scripted they would be able to come up with even more humorous ones.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Maybe it's not so much a matter of whether people that dim really exist, but, in the USA, people want to be on TV so badly they don't care if it's for looking like idiots.

Comment: FWIW, Jay Leno had a similar segment regularly the Tonight Show when he hosted it, going around LA asking dead simple questions and getting stupid responses. Search Youtube for Jaywalking.